# Typing LateX expression in MathJax without displaying as a Math expression

Tags: latex, mathjax, tex, amsmath

On an online tutorial page using `MathJax`, how would we teach students: Type `\[x^2+1\]` to display [image]

Comment: If you teach CS, you may be interested in the new [CS Educator's Stack Exchange](http://cseducators.stackexchange.com) (though since it's still in private beta, it's easiest to enter [through here](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/92460/computer-science-educators))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are actually several similar questions but a thorough answer might be a good reference point for SO.

Ther are two ways of handling this.

#### Escape a particular expression

This is quick and easy and can be done by authors themselves.

As per [the documentation](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#tex-and-latex-in-html-documents), the TeX pre-processors stops parsing at HTML tags. So wrapping the delimiters in some markup will prevent it from rendering

E.g.,`<span>\[</span>x^2+1<span>\]</span>`

#### Skip larger blocks

As per [the documentation](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/options/tex2jax.html), the TeX pre-processor has two configuration options to skip parts of the content:

- `skipTags` (skip by tag name), default: `script,noscript,style,textarea,pre,code`
- `ignoreClass` (skip by class name), default: `tex2jax_ignore`

E.g., `<pre>\[ x^2 + 1 \] </pre>`

Comment: Just an observation: `code` tag (as you mentioned in defaults) would work better in cases where we don't want to use `display:block` since `pre` tag has a default style `display: block`. E.g, the sentence `Type <code>\(ax^2+bx+c=0\)</code> to display quadratic equation` will be all in one line (inline).

Comment: True but the OP had a display style equation.

Comment: Agreed. And thanks to your team for providing us such a powerful tool to display scientific documents on web. I hope [NSF](https://www.nsf.gov/) or some other governmental/private agencies provide some financial support to your team so you can afford to have your own staff support your own [CDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) as that would benefit everyone.